# io_submit waits for all oracle dbwriter I/Os

Tags: arrays, linux, oracle, aio

By way of background, I have been tuning platforms for databases since the 80s. So, I have dealt with a lot of async I/O issues in the past. This one is new, and weird.

First, the I am using Oracle 12c with ASM on RHEL 7.1 64-bit (3.10.0-229). I have been using two EMC CX4-960 arrays with a total of 72 SSDs. I am doing a total of ~105K reads/s, 65K writes/sec. (Yes, that's a pretty beefy storage backend!) The disk write latency is 2-3ms.  When the oracle dbwriters flush buffers (typically in large batches, and async), the following strace fragment shows io_submit() and io_getevents() complete in a couple of milliseconds, it then takes a few milliseconds for all the writes to complete and we move to the next batch. (I got rid of the details of the submitted blocks in the io_submit() lines:

```
294692 12:46:10.173955 io_submit(140662136606720, 301, ) = 301 <0.002482>
294692 12:46:10.178452 io_getevents(140662136606720, 38, 128, , {600, 0}) = 60 <0.000026>
294692 12:46:10.178766 times(NULL)      = 439014359 <0.000016>
294692 12:46:10.178845 io_getevents(140662136606720, 128, 128, , {0, 0}) = 85 <0.000109>
294692 12:46:10.179352 io_getevents(140662136606720, 128, 128, , {0, 0}) = 62 <0.000118>
294692 12:46:10.180207 io_getevents(140662136606720, 94, 128, , {0, 0}) = 76 <0.000115>
294692 12:46:10.180743 io_getevents(140662136606720, 18, 128, , {0, 0}) = 16 <0.000122>
294692 12:46:10.181994 io_getevents(140662136606720, 2, 128, , {0, 0}) = 2 <0.000032>
294692 12:46:10.182393 times(NULL)      = 439014359 <0.000016>
294692 12:46:10.182462 semtimedop(4718593, , 1, {3, 0}) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable) <2.999632>
294692 12:46:13.182193 times(NULL)      = 439014659 <0.000015>
294692 12:46:13.188183 io_submit(140662136606720, 319, ) = 319 <0.002741>
294692 12:46:13.193078 io_getevents(140662136606720, 40, 128, , {600, 0}) = 128 <0.000021>
294692 12:46:13.193583 times(NULL)      = 439014660 <0.000018>
294692 12:46:13.193663 io_getevents(140662136606720, 128, 128, , {0, 0}) = 119 <0.000116>
294692 12:46:13.194364 io_getevents(140662136606720, 72, 128, , {0, 0}) = 59 <0.000123>
294692 12:46:13.195876 io_getevents(140662136606720, 13, 128, , {0, 0}) = 13 <0.000021>
294692 12:46:13.196650 times(NULL)      = 439014661 <0.000017>
294692 12:46:13.196725 semtimedop(4718593, , 1, {2, 990000000}) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable) <2.989363>
294692 12:46:16.186196 times(NULL)      = 439014960 <0.000015>
294692 12:46:16.194006 io_submit(140662136606720, 276, ) = 276 <0.002434>
294692 12:46:16.198285 io_getevents(140662136606720, 36, 128, , {600, 0}) = 42 <0.000017>
294692 12:46:16.198518 times(NULL)      = 439014961 <0.000014>
294692 12:46:16.198572 io_getevents(140662136606720, 128, 128, , {0, 0}) = 48 <0.000092>
294692 12:46:16.198893 io_getevents(140662136606720, 128, 128, , {0, 0}) = 37 <0.000070>
```

So far, so good. I then switched to two Tegile t3600 arrays I am testing. These guys are even faster, and can give me more IOPS at lower latencies. The problem is that I quickly run into Oracle "free buffer waits" at 50% and higher. The dbwriters aren't able to keep up, forcing foreground writes and all kinds of bad things. It's a surprise that the dbwriters can't flush enough buffers with such fast storage. But strace shows why. Note that iostat shows the average disk write latency is right around 0.7ms.

```
19131 18:35:06.903628 io_submit(140538814074880, 517, ) = 517 <0.505505>
19131 18:35:07.414281 io_getevents(140538814074880, 40, 128, , {600, 0}) = 128 <0.000014>
19131 18:35:07.415091 io_getevents(140538814074880, 128, 128, , {0, 0}) = 128 <0.000012>
19131 18:35:07.416139 io_getevents(140538814074880, 128, 128, , {0, 0}) = 128 <0.000010>
19131 18:35:07.417134 semctl(753668, 33, SETVAL, 0x1) = 0 <0.000017>
19131 18:35:07.417553 semctl(688130, 103, SETVAL, 0x1) = 0 <0.000014>
19131 18:35:07.417640 semctl(655361, 130, SETVAL, 0x1) = 0 <0.000013>
19131 18:35:07.419923 io_submit(140538814074880, 248, ) = 248 <0.250174>
19131 18:35:07.673864 io_getevents(140538814074880, 22, 128, , {600, 0}) = 128 <0.000019>
19131 18:35:07.674735 io_getevents(140538814074880, 128, 128, , {0, 0}) = 128 <0.000010>
19131 18:35:07.676021 io_getevents(140538814074880, 128, 128, , {0, 0}) = 128 <0.000020>
19131 18:35:07.676660 semctl(753668, 5, SETVAL, 0x1) = 0 <0.000021>
19131 18:35:07.680954 io_submit(140538814074880, 507, ) = 507 <0.503491>
19131 18:35:08.190096 io_getevents(140538814074880, 38, 128, , {600, 0}) = 128 <0.000010>
19131 18:35:08.190617 io_getevents(140538814074880, 128, 128, , {0, 0}) = 128 <0.000008>
19131 18:35:08.193571 io_getevents(140538814074880, 128, 128, , {0, 0}) = 128 <0.000025>
19131 18:35:08.196128 semctl(720899, 38, SETVAL, 0x1) = 0 <0.000026>
```

So, for some reason, io_submit() with 517 blocks takes 505ms to return. Why?

Any ideas why this might be happening?  It appears that the array is somehow telling the OS to issue the writes serially. FWIW, I have even enabled write-back caching of writes in the array controllers. So it appears to be something in the OS itself

Comment: interesting problem, but beyond my experience. I'm not sure, but maybe more appropriate to http://dba.stackexchange.com ? Good luck.

Comment: possibly offtopic: I recall that on AIX there was a tunable parameter queue depth. Is it possible that there were more requests submitted than supported by the hardware?

Comment: I'm afraid that your problem is so special that, the next step would be adding printk into kernel driver source.

Comment: @ibre541: The queue depths (/sys/block/sd*/queue/nr_requests) are set to 256 in both cases.

Comment: are you reading/writing straight to the block-device? Otherwise I would suspect the filesystem is performing some operations in blocking calls. like metadata operations.

Comment: @Arvid: Yes, straight to block device. The LUNs are managed by ASM

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when Linux scans the LUNs, the LUN advertises itself with “Write cache enabled”. This tells Linux it has to use Force Unit Access to avoid data loss in case of power loss in the cache since Oracle opens the LUN with O_SYNC (or O_DSYNC?). This is based on many presumptions – the cache is in RAM, is volatile, etc. – but let’s just accept that. FUA is bad news when it comes to performance. It also defeats the parallel issuing of async I/Os.

It turns out the array has a setting that tells it whether to advertise a Write Back Cache to the Linux server or not. It doesn’t change how the array operates; it just changes how it appears to the host. By changing the WBC setting on the array to Disabled, the Linux host prints the line “Write cache disabled” when it scans the LUN, and now async writes behave as normal.